# Handlebars and Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

It's a good practice to include `js` file as `partials` in **Handlebars**?
I mean, I need to use some data from `nodejs` in my `jquery`-based javascript, and to do this I load my `js` as `partials` in handlebars template and then use handlebars notation directly, this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myVar = {{value_from_db}};
});
```

I know this it's not the correct way, I hope I've explained what I need.

In my case, I need to use `MapBox` coordinates inside the `js`, where the coordinates are get from database, this way:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {
        zoomControl: false,
        attributionControl: false
    }).setView([my_lat, my_lng], 3);
```

Comment: how may my_lat, my_lng rows exists in your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your value_from_db is unique ok, otherwise "No. Do not do this."

When your js files are static, browser will cache them and do not download them again. But your js files are changing, how will you tell browser your file changed. Implementing this logic will be hard for you to do.

a.js , v1

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myVar = 20;
});
```

a.js , v2

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myVar = 30;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so you can suggest me the best practice?